# Bower dependency not installed

Tags: javascript, bower

Playing around with Bower and using it to install [livestampjs](http://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/). Livestamp has a dependency of [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) but installing livestamp via `bower install livestampjs` isn't installing moment. Looking at the livestamp bower.json remotely it does declare the dependency but this file is missing locally (.bower.json is present). Am I doing something wrong here or is there just an issue with this package?

This is the bower.json for livestampjs

```
{
  "name": "livestamp",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "ignore": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "*",
    "moment": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: What (if any) exact errors do you get when attempting `bower install`? And what are the contents of `bower.json`?

Comment: no errors from bower install, added bower.json above

Comment: Hmm not sure. Try `bower install`ing momentjs manually first?

Comment: i can just install momentjs on its own but doesn't that make the whole dependency management thing a bit useless!

Comment: Agreed. Does changing the dependency to `"moment": "moment/moment"` (using the github path instead of a wildcard version) affect anything?

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean, are you suggesting forking the repo and trying to update the bower file?

Comment: No, I'm just suggesting a troubleshooting path. From the bower.json spec, the above seems correct, but trying the other `dependencies` formats might help figure out what is going on.

Comment: So what's weird is cloning the git repo and then running `bower install` installs dependencies as intended. Is it possible that version bower is pointing to is wrong or has an invalid bower.json?

Comment: @brbcoding don't think so, if I `bower search livestamp` there's only one package

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm right... if you run `bower info livestampjs`, you'll see the contents of the json file that is cached on bower. there are no dependencies listed. [`bower info livestampjs`](https://gist.github.com/brbcoding/a3639fd712f33f1ee21c)

Comment: @brbcoding good catch, any idea how to get that cache updated?

Comment: @brbcoding oh yeah, and add that as an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: Can't figure out how to fix the stock `bower install` one without an updated code push from the livestamp maintainers, but forcing the master branch seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I previously commented 'Yeah, I think I'm right... if you run `bower info livestampjs`, you'll see the contents of the json file that is cached on bower. there are no dependencies listed. [`bower info livestampjs`](https://gist.github.com/brbcoding/a3639fd712f33f1ee21c)'... This may be correct, and the only way around that that I know of is to force it to use the master branch...

`bower install git://github.com/mattbradley/livestampjs.git#master`

Which installs all dependencies as expected.

Comment: Sweet worked for me as wel. Strangely, the package I was installing, `combodate` also had `momentjs` as a dependency which didn't install.